# javascript triggering event when p element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program in raw javascript. When a `<p>` element is clicked I wish this to trigger a function which adds the price of the element to the total. Please see my code below.

JS

```
function loadJSONDoc()
{
  var answer;
  var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    answer = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
    var items = answer[0].prices[0];

    for(var index in items) {

      var node = document.getElementById("orderList");
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      var price = items[index];
      p.setAttribute("class", price)
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(index + " price = " + price);
      p.appendChild(textnode);
      node.appendChild(p);
      };
    }

var total = 0;
var update = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
update.onclick = function(){
  ///code here to update total based on element id
}
```

After the JSON object has been returned and my html page has been updated it looks like this:

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
     </head>
     <body>
      <ul id="orderList">
         <p class="4.75">Cafe Latte price = 4.75</p>
         <p class="4.75">Flat White price = 4.75</p>
         <p class="3.85">Cappucinoprice = 3.85</p>
     </ul>
     <script src="js/getData.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I am able to target one `<p>` element by using the following code, however I am looking for a solution whereby my function will trigger if I click on ANY `<p>` element, which will in turn update the total based on the value of such `<p>` element's class. I hope this makes sense.

```
var update = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    update.onclick = function(){
     ///code here to update total based on element id
    }
```

Thanks, Paul

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: ok, let me change to class

Comment: updated question, apologies

Comment: You can add event to ul#orderList click, the event will bubble up.

Comment: Another side note, classes can't start with numbers.

Comment: really appreciate the extra detail @j08691, however, how do you mean? That they are strings, and not numbers?

Comment: No I mean that the first character of any CSS class name can't be a number.

Comment: @j08691 just to confirm this only applies to classes, not ids?

Comment: Classes and ID names must also be meaningful to the developer. A lot of people underestimate thinking about good class names and id's.

Comment: Correct, in HTML5 IDs can begin with numbers.

Comment: @Mikey, good point, I am aware of this. I thought for the purpose of what I am trying to do - adding to the total - that it would be a good idea to add the price as a class name. This would then allow me to add to the total, however this is not working as expected. May need a different tactic

Comment: @j08691 apologies if this is not the forum for this. Taking your point on board, regarding class names not allowed to begin with a number. I followed the solution provided below and following on I was able to add to the total. Bearing this in mind, is it that CSS styling will not work on this element if it has this classname? or is it more of a standard practice? I have just looked at some articles online, but was hoping you could clarify

Comment: _"is it that CSS styling will not work on this element if it has this classname?"_ Correct

Comment: wonderful, thanks @j08691, have learned a number of things following the post, great stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind each item in `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`. You are only doing it for the first one. For example:

```
var update = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for( var i = 0; i < update.length; ++i ) {
    update[i].onclick = function() { 
       //code here to update total based on element id
    }
}
```

*Note:* You can access the value of the `<p>` elements class by doing `this.className` inside the `onclick` function.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, this is what I was looking for. thanks v much